# How to add responsive background image on Bootstrap Modal header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have to add a background image to modal header and it should be responsive as well. I am able to add the image but I am getting issues in making it responsive. Any help appreciated.

Below is the sample snippet.

```css
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(https://s9.postimg.org/ky3v3mduz/Jellyfish.jpg);
    height: 208px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    .close {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      float: right;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      &:hover {
        color: @hover-blush;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `background-size: cover; background-position: center center;` assuming you want the center of the image to be the part that is always shown. Otherwise, adjust those as needed to ensure the focal point of the image will be shown.

```css
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(https://s9.postimg.org/ky3v3mduz/Jellyfish.jpg);
    height: 208px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;

    .close {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      float: right;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      &:hover {
        color: @hover-blush;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: If we use background-size: cover, then it scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. And some areas may not be in view. I do not want this.

Comment: @Harsheet you should add these details to your post. What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

To have a responsive background image, what you're looking for is a percentage-based [`background-size`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp). To completely cover the content area, you would use:

```
.modal-header {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```css
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(https://s9.postimg.org/ky3v3mduz/Jellyfish.jpg);
    height: 208px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    .close {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      float: right;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      &:hover {
        color: @hover-blush;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Note that this will distort the image, which may not be what you want. In order to not distort the image, you should only specify a single parameter in `background-size`, and also tell the background to be fixed to the center:

```
.modal-header {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```css
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(https://s9.postimg.org/ky3v3mduz/Jellyfish.jpg);
    height: 208px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;

    .close {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      float: right;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      &:hover {
        color: @hover-blush;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Ultimately, considering the modal header itself will never change in height, you may want to look into simply using an `<img>` tag instead of a `background-image`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think this will distort the image

Comment: Yes, it would. Keep in mind that you can provide a single parameter though, and tweak to your liking. `background-size: 100%` will retain the image proportions, but some of the image will get cut off (on the y-axis). It depends on how you want it to 'respond'. The modal header **itself** can't change in height, so if you want a responsive image that scales, you'd be better off using an `<img>` tag.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide an alternate approach, which is likely more desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to have is a right size image and changing the background-size to cover.

```css
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(http://www.bahai.org/chrome/img/beliefs/bahaullah-covenant-feature-img.jpg?3e7a0319);
    height: 208px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   

    .close {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      float: right;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      &:hover {
        color: @hover-blush;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```